# php tags inside echo expression

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a multiple choice quiz where I will be displaying only 1 question per page, where the answer choices are shuffled to be displayed to the user.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","labquiz");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$res = mysql_query("SELECT multiplechoiceid, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, answer, description FROM multiple_choice");

$ans_array = array('choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3', 'answer');
    shuffle($ans_array);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    echo $row["multiplechoiceid"]. ".". $row["question"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo '<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->multiplechoiceid?>" value="$ans_array[0]" required> <?=$ans_array[0]?>';
    echo "<br>";
    echo '<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->multiplechoiceid?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>"> <?=$ans_array[1]?>';
    echo "<br>";
    echo '<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->multiplechoiceid?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>"> <?=$ans_array[2]?>';
    echo "<br>";
    echo '<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->multiplechoiceid?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>"> <?=$ans_array[3]?>';
    echo "<br>";
}   
?>
```

The php tags in the echo expressions do not display the answer choices but only the radio buttons are being displayed.

Comment: in your post have two things 1. mysqli and 2.mysql. Recommend to use `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: You cannot write like name="quizid<?=$row->multiplechoiceid?>" in echo.
you have to concate php variable like name="quizid'.$row->multiplechoiceid.'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not separate your php & html code & write like this -

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 
 echo $row["multiplechoiceid"]. ".". $row["question"]; ?>
 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->multiplechoiceid?>" value="$ans_array[0]" required> <?=$ans_array[0]?>
 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->multiplechoiceid?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>"> <?=$ans_array[1]?>
 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->multiplechoiceid?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>"> <?=$ans_array[2]?>
 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->multiplechoiceid?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>"> <?=$ans_array[3]?>
 <br>
<?php  } ?>
```

If still face problem then check short code is enabled inside your php.ini file